# Flex item content overflow in IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum vel pretium tellus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.flex-container {
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: -ms-flexbox;  /* For IE10 */
    display: flex;  /* For modern browsers. */ 
}
```

The code is available in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kd7W3/4/).
Unfortunately, in IE10 inner 'p' tag causes overflow, but in modern browsers everything is OK. How can I fix it in IE10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in IE 10. Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joydesigner/LWEGC/)

The fix css is as following:

```
.flex-container {
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: flex;  /* For modern browsers. */
    display: flexbox;  /* For IE10 */
}
```